# Look of TComboBox changes after removing Drag&Drop component from Borland c++ Builder 2009 project

Tags: delphi, combobox, drag-and-drop, themes, borland-c++

I noticed something strange, related to the Drag&Drop component from Anders Melander, and I wonder if anybody has an idea ?

I have been looking for the reason, without much success.  However the effect is 100% repeatable by simply removing: `DropFileTarget->Register(ComboBox);` from the project's constructor.

The other day I noticed that the drop down box on my application was not looking right:

[image: wrong combo]

Whereas it previously looked (correct) like this:

[image: good combo]

So I started going back to figure out at what time the look of the component broke and I have now been able to trace the change in look 100% to:

```
DropFileTarget->Register(ComboBox);
```

If this line is present, the look is good.
If I remove this line of code from the form's constructor the look of the drop box is wrong !?

I actually wanted to remove DropFileTarget completely from my project since I now use [another method to catch a dragged file](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=105484).

Can anybody please tell me what `Register()` does here to change the look of the component, so that I can set the look back to what it should be.

My gut says it has to do with theme support as well somehow ?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION BASED ON THE COMMENTS:**

I did some tests.  A normal looking Combobox, with theme support, looks like this:
[image]

With theme support disabled it looks like this:
[image]

In other words, the Drag&Drop component's Register() creates a special look, that I had grown used to, and of which I thought was the correct look.
The canvas where the text is displayed is white instead of grey (default settings).

I'm now torn between going for 'how it should be' or trying to create the look I had gotten used to.

Anybody knows what properties I should change to get the component-influenced look (second screenshot from the top) ?

Comment: I've tried to edit the Q to replace the c++ tag with the delphi tag since c++ is irrelevant to the problem and the delphi tag would get the attention of those that actually knows something about how the VCL works. The edit was rejected.

Comment: Thanks SpeedFreak, I changed the c++ tag to the Delphi tag !  
Nice that the pictures are embedded now.

Comment: *Can anybody please tell me what Register() does?* You have the source code. You can see what it does. If you really want help then an SSCCE makes it easy for us to give you that help. I've seen artifacts like this with combo boxes. But I cannot help without a reproduction. And I don't want to try to guess how to make one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes he has the source but what it does may be obvious to you and me but not to Peter :-). Anyway, `Register` does two things; it calls `RegisterDragDrop` on the target and creates a hidden child control of the target so it can detect if/when the window handle of the target control is recreated (e.g. if a control is docked/undocked). If the handle is recreated it unregisters the old handle and registers the new. To see if this child control is the cause of the "correct" combo look set the `TDropFileTarget.AutoRegister` property to False. This disables use of the child control.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that your "correct" look isn't the abnormal one? The "incorrect" combo looks like a regular `TComboBox` with `Style=csDropDownList` should. See: [About Combo Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm going to dig a bit deeper and try to give some answers wrt the look on Monday !  Sorry guys but this is one of those rare weekends away from the compiler ;)  I want to say away from the computer, but this post doesn't exactly support that claim :)

Comment: I did some more tests and indeed, the ComboBox look influenced by Register() doesn't look like the ComboBox normally does.  I had gotten so used to it that I thought **that** was the correct look !

Comment: If you really want the old (now incorrect) look then I suggest you ownerdraw the combobox. It's fairly simple and AFAIR it's possible to differentiate between the list items and the edit item.

Comment: SpeedFreak, out of interest, do you happen to know why Register() causes this behaviour ?

Comment: I haven't got a clue. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks all !!!  I think I'm going to stick with the 'correct' look (previously thought to be incorrect)  I've gotten used to it  :-)